# Circle the Background Image with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background

I have 3 images - back_about_1.jpg,back_about_2.jpg,back_about_3.jpg

I have a div ID'ed -about-`<div id="about"></div>`

My default background of the div is back_about_1.jpg (  set through css- `background: url(../img/back_about_1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;`)

I want to change the background of this div every 5 seconds and after the code has changed the background to 3rd image, I want to circle it back to the first image.

Any Help with Jquery would be nice guys :)

Comment: Tried something that was already here
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   var imageID=0;
   var aboutimg = document.getElementByID("about");
   function changeimage(every_seconds){
   if(!imageID){
    aboutimg.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/back_about_1.jpg)";
   imageID++;
   }
   else{if(imageID==1){
    aboutimg.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/back_about_2.jpg)";
   imageID++;
   }else{if(imageID==2){
    aboutimg.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/back_about_3.jpg)";
   imageID=0;
   }}}
   setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*1000));
   }
  </script>

Comment: @chepe263 Yup Thank you removed that part of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like:

```
#about{
  background: 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;
}
```

This would do the trick:

```
$(function(){
   //Possible images
   var images = ["img/back_about_1.jpg", "img/back_about_2.jpg", "img/back_about_3.jpg"];
   (function changeBg(index){
        $("#about").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + images[index] +')');
        setTimeout(function(){
            changeBg((index + 1) % images.length);  //This cycles
        }, 5000);
   })(0);

});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Man :D Thanks a lottttttttt :) It helped.. 
*One little tweak was to remove the "../" from the images variable,but once I did that it was cool. Thanks man :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :). Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 0):

[**Here's an additional JQuery solution.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Ac2bs/3/)

To set this up, you need to nest 3 div's that have a background declared within another div. Like so:

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
    <div id="rotatingImage1"></div>
    <div id="rotatingImage2"></div>
    <div id="rotatingImage3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#rotatingImage1{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/501/') no-repeat;position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;}
#rotatingImage2{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/502/') no-repeat;position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;}
#rotatingImage3{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/503/') no-repeat;position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;}
```

And here's the JQuery Snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function(){
        $('.fadein div:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
             .next('div').fadeIn(1000)
             .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
          2000);
    });
});
```